# Encrypted JSON Strings Over SSL for Webservice Security

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, ssl, asmx

I have a scenario where users are Uploading Transactions logs to Main Server Via ASMX Webservice. The application is clickonce .Net winforms app

Currently I am doing this To convert to List of Object to Json and Deserialize it on Service. over the SSL.

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Values_Static.logitems);
```

My Code is protected by SmartAssembly . And still I am getting some breach that attacker have access to the Network Connections and Can Deserliaze the Data.

Now i am thinking of a Scenario that I Encrypt the Json String with some private string key and then decypt it on the server .

e.g

```
private string salt = "$e7?8f@l4";
return ByteArrToString(Encrypt(TextValue + salt));
```

Hardcode the key in app and decode it in server.

will it work ? 
Users are uploading the the logs to server every minute and there are possibly 20-30 entries per Upload.
is there any chances of broken Data or  still the hacking ?

UPDATE :
According to Discussion Below . I understand that there is some issue with my Code. The code is accepting the invalid certificate . How i Can prevent to Accept only Valid Certificate from my https:// Web service .
ATM , every one can see the code through fiddler with Decryption HTTPS on .

I have a valid Certificate installed on my IIS 7. and its working properly 
the issue is with code. and its standard auto generated web reference in Visual Studio.

**UPDATE 2 :
The Final Result is , The Post data is not Encrypting , its Plain XML and readable by any software that can sniff , however the GET data is secure . I had serached bit not found some valid Answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SSL?  If so, any application-level encryption is redundant.  And, the key will have to be embedded in the code, so is readable by any attacker.

Comment: yes the Webservice is accesing Via https:// and its the Valid Certificate from comodo . but still i can see the data via Fiddler ? i just dont understand if it is encrypted how can i see the data and if i can see then definatley other will be able to ?  and about the key , is it still hack able if my code is encrypted by smart assembly by red gate.

Comment: Use wireshark to see what an attacker might have access to.

Comment: 1) fiddler is essentially a man-in-the-middle interception and works because the client code doesn't verify the certificate. There is information on how fiddler works on their site. 2) smart assembly is a deterrent, but does not guarantee that it can't be decompiled. You cannot make your code 100% secure.

Comment: How Can i make it only accept the Connections if Certification is verified ?

Comment: The Final : **POST data is not encrypting . The Get data is encrypted . Any one can show me light why this is , i had tried Google but not found something solid like answer.**

Comment: You're sure you're POSTing via SSL also?

Comment: Hi ,the reference i added of web service is with https but as the fiddler can read i seems its not making attempt via SSL , But receive them in SSL , i am stuck on this one can any one point me out in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler (or other HTTPS proxies) can decrypt *any* HTTPS traffic.

You could prevent simple use of Fiddler by requiring a specific server certificate in your client code (rather than trusting any certificate the system itself trusts). However, this is only a weak deterrent because the user could just decompile your code and alter it so that your new certificate check is neutered.

This is called the "Untrusted client" problem, and it's the same thing that makes Digital Rights Management (DRM) software a "best effort" affair rather than an ironclad protection.

Comment: Fiddler can't decrypt traffic where client-certificate authentication is used (unless it's also given the private key for that certificate). In addition, Fiddler can only decrypt traffic provided that the original client is willing (that is, when it accepts a fake certificate).